# Using Index annotation on superclass with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an abstract superclass which every Entity on my domain is a subclass of it.

Using DB schema generation, I want to create an Index for each Entity, on a field on the superclass, and without using the Table annotation on every subclass.

My superclass

```java
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
        private Long surrogateId;

        @Index(name="id_index") // Every subclass should inherit this index, with its own name
        @Column(unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

An example of subclass

```java
    @Entity
    public class Customer extends BaseEntity {
        ...
    }
```

I tried so far:

- use the **Table** annotation with @Index on the superclass, but Hibernate
  doesn't seem to use that annotation if it is not marked with @Entity. 
  For example
  `@Table(indexes = {@Index(name="index_id", columnList = "id")})` 
  No SQL statements are generated.
- use the **deprecated @Index** annotation with a name "id_index", but only one index
  is created on startup (the db raises an error that this index already
  exists for other entities). Some generated SQL statements:

```
    Hibernate: create index id_index on "customer" ("id")

    Hibernate: create index id_index on "user" ("id")

    2020-02-15 17:47:26,620 WARN  o.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create index id_index on "customer" ("id")" via JDBC Statement
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "id_index" already exists
```

Any ideas on how to do this without too much code duplication?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example of sub class? and the generated sql statements?

Comment: @Jens Sure, updated.

Comment: can you try to remove the name of the index?

Comment: @Jens It is mandatory, cannot be removed

Comment: I do not think so: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Index.html: name
(Optional) The name of the index.

Comment: @Jens You´re checking the wrong annotation. Index from persistence package cannot be used in a field. This Index annotation is from Hibernate, which it is already deprecated (in favor of using Table annotation at class level)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see to do this - and it appears more trouble than it is worth to simply avoid placing an `@Table` annotation on each Entity  - is to create a custom dialect and override the `getIndexExporter()` method:

```
public class MyPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLXXDialect{

    @Override
    public Exporter<Index> getIndexExporter() {
            return new MyIndexExporter(this);
        }
    }
```

to return a customized Exporter, most likely extending org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardIndexExporter

```
public class MyIndexExporter extends StandardIndexExporter{

    public MyIndexExporter(Dialect dialect){
        super(dialect);
    }        

    @Override
    public String[] getSqlCreateStrings(Index index, Metadata metadata) {
      //looks like you'd need to paste the whole code from superclass method
      //and alter the index name accordingly

      indexNameForCreation = index.getTable().getQualifiedTableName() + 
               "_" + index.getName();

      //in the default implementation it is simply index.getName()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alan Hay** answer may work but it seems a bit of overengineering... So I decided to not use schema generation and use **Liquibase** instead, so I can have more control over the database.

Anyway, If anyone is having the same problem with schema generation, I tried with **@Index** (using eclipselink) and it worked, so this issue is only in Hibernate.